# How to "filter" and "format" namespaces based on the annotation

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I want to filter namespaces based on the annotation. I do not want namespace which has annotation as `components\.gke\.io/layer=="addon"`.

I tried `kubectl get ns -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations.components\.gke\.io/layer=="addon")].metadata.name}'` command and at least it gives me the result but it is not coming in normal table format, the way it comes when you execute `kubectl get ns`.

[image]

However, this is not what I want, I want the inverse of this, which means filtering out these GKE rows. I tried `kubectl get ns -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations.components\.gke\.io/layer=="")].metadata.name}'` but it doesn't work, it give empty result.

I tried to format but unable to create the desired command. Anyone has tried this before - (1.) filter out namespaces which has certain annotation (2.) format that output in table format.

Comment: `kubectl`'s [JSONPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) support does not appear to support negation. Consider a JSON processing tool (such as [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)) as this will provide more comprehensive functionality (and gives you a generic JSON processing solution for other commands).Because you're using `--output=jsonpath`, you override the `kubectl` command's default table formatting (and you can't then have `kubectl` use (table) format. You could pipe the output (from `kubectl --output=json` or `jq`) into e.g. Bash's `column` to achieve similar

Comment: @DazWilkin, I could make this `kubectl get ns -o json | jq '.items[] | "name1: " + .metadata.name + " <> name2: " + .metadata.namespace'`.. but not able to filter the output using this.

Comment: I'm out this afternoon but I'll try to get you an example when I'm home this evening. You'll want to use jq's `select`.

Comment: Try: `kubectl get namespaces --output=json | jq -r '["NAME","STATUS"],(.items[]|[select(.metadata.annotations["components.gke.io/layer"]!="addon")|.metadata.name,.status.phase])|@tsv' | column --table --separator $'\t'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think (!?) you can't use negation with `kubectl`'s implementation of [JSONPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/).

Once you use the `--output` flag with `kubectl`, you lose the ability to render the command's output using the default table format. With e.g. Bash [`column`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) can provide similar out.

Consider using a generic JSON processing tool  such as [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

An advantage of using a standalone tool is that, once you're familiar with the tool, you can use it with any command that emits JSON (not just with `kubectl`.

```bash
FILTER='
  ["NAME","STATUS"],
(.items[]| 
  [
    select(.metadata.annotations["components.gke.io/layer"]!="addon")
    |.metadata.name,.status.phase
  ]
)
|@tsv'

kubectl get namespaces --output=json \
| jq -r "${FILTER}" \
| column --table --separator $'\t'
```

Explanation of `FILTER`:

1. Returns a JSON array that is piped into `@tsv` (tab-formatted output)
2. The first array entry is a an array (!) of column titles
3. `.items` is piped through a `select` that filters Namespaces that don't contain the `annotation`
4. Emit not filtered Namespace name and status as JSON array items

The tab-formatted (no longer JSON) that's emitted by `jq` is then piped into `column` which formats the results as a table.